# How to use Vectorization with NumPy arrays to calculate geodesic distance using Geopy library for a large dataset?

Tags: python, numpy, coordinates, vectorization, geopy

I am trying to calculate geodesic distance from a dataframe which consists of four columns of latitude and longitude data with around 3 million rows. I used the apply lambda method to do it but it took 18 minutes to finish the task. Is there a way to use Vectorization with NumPy arrays to speed up the calculation? Thank you for answering.

My code using apply and lambda method:

```
from geopy import distance

df['geo_dist'] = df.apply(lambda x: distance.distance(
                              (x['start_latitude'], x['start_longitude']),
                              (x['end_latitude'], x['end_longitude'])).miles, axis=1)
```

Updates:

I am trying this code but it gives me the error: ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all(). Appreciate if anyone can help.

```
df['geo_dist'] = distance.distance(
                          (df['start_latitude'].values, df['start_longitude'].values),
                          (df['end_latitude'].values, df['end_longitude'].values)).miles
```

Comment: Geopy distance routines don't support vectorization currently. Perhaps @cffk, the author of geodesic routines, might suggest a solution there?

This issue is being tracked in https://github.com/geopy/geopy/issues/189

Answer (score 4):

I think you might consider using `geopandas` for this, it's an extension of pandas (and therefore `numpy`) designed to do these types of calculations very quickly.

Specifically, it [has a method for calculating the distance between sets of points in a `GeoSeries`](http://geopandas.org/reference.html#GeoSeries.distance), which can be a column of a `GeoDataFrame`. I’m fairly certain that this method leverages `numexpr` for vectorization.

It should look something like this, where you convert your data frame to a `GeoDataFrame` with (at least) two `GeoSeries` columns that you can use for the origin and point destinations. This should return a `GeoSeries` object:

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point

geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(df.longitude, df.latitude)]
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, crs={'init': 'epsg:4326'}, geometry=geometry)

distances = gdf.geometry.distance(gdf.destination_geometry)
```

Comment: Where does gdf.destination_geometry come from? I got it to work by creating a dest_geometry using a different set of longitudes and latitudes, creating a dest_gdf, then calling gdf.geometry.distance(dest_gdf.geometry).

Also, that gpd.GeoDataFrame line gives a FutureWarning on the authority code. As best I can tell the line should be:
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, crs='epsg:4326', geometry=geometry)

Comment: The geopandas distance calculation makes use of GEOS to calculate distance.  The GEOS calculations are all linear.  Thus, this solution does not provide a geodesic distance.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to your question: You cannot do what you want to do with `geopy`. I am not familiar with this package but the error traceback shows that this function and possibly all other functions in this package were not written/designed with vectorized computations in mind.

Now, if you can do with great-circle distances, then I would suggest that you experiment with [`astropy.coordinates`](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/coordinates/) package that my be able to compute [`separations`](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/coordinates/matchsep.html#separations) between points in a vectorial way.

Here is an example based on my answer to a different question: [Finding closest point](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45134554/8033585):

```
from astropy.units import Quantity
from astropy.coordinates import SkyCoord, EarthLocation
from astropy.constants import R_earth
import numpy as np

lon1 = Quantity([-71.312796, -87.645307, -87.640426, -87.635513,
                 -87.630629, -87.625793 ], unit='deg')
lat1 = Quantity([41.49008, 41.894577, 41.894647, 41.894713,
                 41.894768, 41.894830], unit='deg')
lon2 = Quantity([-81.695391, -87.645307 + 0.5, -87.640426, -87.635513 - 0.5,
                 -87.630629 + 1.0, -87.625793 - 1.0], unit='deg')
lat2 = Quantity([41.499498, 41.894577 - 0.5, 41.894647, 41.894713 - 0.5,
                 41.894768 - 1.0, 41.894830 + 1.0], unit='deg')

pts1 = SkyCoord(EarthLocation.from_geodetic(lon1, lat1, height=R_earth).itrs, frame='itrs')
pts2 = SkyCoord(EarthLocation.from_geodetic(lon2, lat2, height=R_earth).itrs, frame='itrs')
```

Then, distances between the two sets of points can be computed as:

```
>>> dist = pts2.separation(pts1)
>>> print(dist)
<Angle [ 7.78350849, 0.62435354, 0., 0.62435308, 1.25039805, 1.24353876] deg>
```

Approximate conversion to distance:

```
>>> np.deg2rad(pts2.separation(pts1)) * R_earth / u.rad
<Quantity [ 866451.17527216,  69502.31527953,      0.        ,
             69502.26348614, 139192.86680148, 138429.29874024] m>
```

Compare the first value with what you would get from the `geopy`'s example:

```
>>> distance.distance((41.49008, -71.312796), (41.499498, -81.695391)).meters
866455.4329098687
```

EDIT: Actually, quite possibly this may actually give you the geodesic distance that you are after but make sure to check [the description of `EarthLocation`](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.coordinates.EarthLocation.html#).

Answer (score 0):

Going back and forth with numpy:

```
from geopy import distance

lats = df['latitude'].values
lons = df['longitude'].values
latsNext = np.roll(lats, 1)
lonsNext = np.roll(lons, 1)
dists = [distance.distance((lat0, lon0),(lat1, lon1)).kilometers for lat0, lon0, lat1, lon1 in zip(lats, lons, latsNext, lonsNext)]
dists = np.roll(dists, -1)
dists[-1] = np.nan
df['distance'] = dists
```

Answer (score 0):

See a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69556412/with-a-dataframe-that-contains-coordinates-find-other-rows-with-coordinates-wit) with a much faster alternative.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def haversine(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):
    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = np.radians([lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])
    dlon = lon2 - lon1
    dlat = lat2 - lat1

    haver_formula = np.sin(dlat/2)**2 + np.cos(lat1) * np.cos(lat2) * np.sin(dlon/2)**2

    r = 3958.756 #6371 for distance in KM for miles use 3958.756
    dist = 2 * r * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(haver_formula))
    return pd.Series(dist)


df['dist'] = haversine(df['start_latitude'], df['start_longitude'], df['end_latitude'], df['end_longitude'])
```

Comment: The haversine equation is only intended for short distances and when precision isn't too important as it assumes a spherical Earth.