# Applying function without using apply to every row in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking for fastest way to get distance between two latitude and longitude. One pair is from user and the other pair is from `marker`. Below is my code :

```
import geopy
import pandas as pd


marker = pd.read_csv(file_path)
coords_2 = (4.620881605,101.119911)
marker['Distance'] = round(geopy.distance.geodesic((marker['Latitude'].values,marker['Longitude'].values), (coords_2)).m,2)
```

Previously, I used `apply` which is extremely slow :

```
marker['Distance2'] = marker.apply(lambda x: round(geopy.distance.geodesic((x.Latitude,x.Longitude), (coords_2)).m,2), axis = 1)
```

Then, I used Pandas Series vectorization :

```
marker['Distance'] = round(geopy.distance.geodesic((marker['Latitude'].values,marker['Longitude'].values), (coords_2)).m,2)
```

I'm receiving error :

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

I added `all()` and `any()` to test (such that `marker['Latitude'].values.all(),marker['Longitude'].values.all()` and vice versa). However, the result calculated was entirely wrong from both `any()` and `all()`.

This is my result:

```
    Latitude    Longitude   Distance    Distance2
0   4.620882    101.119911  11132307.42 0.00
1   4.620125    101.120399  11132307.42 99.72
2   4.619368    101.120885  11132307.42 199.26
```

where `Distance` is the result from vectorization which is INCORRECT, whereas `Distance2` is the result from using `apply` which is CORRECT. Simply, `Distance2` is my expected outcome.

**WITHOUT USING** `apply`, I want to produce faster result with correct output.

Comment: try swifter or modin pandas with apply function
https://github.com/jmcarpenter2/swifter


https://github.com/modin-project/modin

Comment: I found the other question with a search for *geopy + numpy*. Even if it is now old, I still think it relevant, specifically the `geopandas` part. Ping me in a comment if it is not enough to solve your problem and just tell me why if you want me to reopen the question.

Comment: Can you share the other one as well? I'm looking through it now @SergeBallesta

Comment: It seems impossible to install geopandas!

Comment: @SergeBallesta your suggestion didn't work. Sorry

Comment: I have reopened the question, but I am afraid that you will not find better answers that the ones from [How to use Vectorization with NumPy arrays to calculate geodesic distance using Geopy library for a large dataset?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50275057/3545273)

Comment: I'm referring to the one you suggested at the moment.